# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'contrib' in tensorflow 2.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to run mean iou in tensorflow 2.0
inside the code I am using a line

```
tf.contrib.metrics.aggregate_metric_map()
```

but while running the code I am getting an error as

```
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'contrib'
```

How can we access `aggregate_metric_map()` in TF 2.0?

Answer (score 0):

You can just copy the function from old `tensorflow` repository as it doesn't have any special dependency.

ref: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.8/tensorflow/contrib/metrics/python/ops/metric_ops.py

```
def aggregate_metric_map(names_to_tuples):
  """Aggregates the metric names to tuple dictionary.
  This function is useful for pairing metric names with their associated value
  and update ops when the list of metrics is long. For example:
  python
    metrics_to_values, metrics_to_updates = slim.metrics.aggregate_metric_map({
        'Mean Absolute Error': new_slim.metrics.streaming_mean_absolute_error(
            predictions, labels, weights),
        'Mean Relative Error': new_slim.metrics.streaming_mean_relative_error(
            predictions, labels, labels, weights),
        'RMSE Linear': new_slim.metrics.streaming_root_mean_squared_error(
            predictions, labels, weights),
        'RMSE Log': new_slim.metrics.streaming_root_mean_squared_error(
            predictions, labels, weights),
    })

  Args:
    names_to_tuples: a map of metric names to tuples, each of which contain the
      pair of (value_tensor, update_op) from a streaming metric.
  Returns:
    A dictionary from metric names to value ops and a dictionary from metric
    names to update ops.
  """
  metric_names = names_to_tuples.keys()
  value_ops, update_ops = zip(*names_to_tuples.values())
  return dict(zip(metric_names, value_ops)), dict(zip(metric_names, update_ops))
```

Answer (score -1):

Tensorflow 2.0 does not have contrib module. Here is a quote from TF documentation

> A large amount of older TensorFlow 1.x code uses the Slim library, which was packaged with TensorFlow 1.x as tf.contrib.layers. **As a contrib module, this is no longer available in TensorFlow 2.0**, even in tf.compat.v1. Converting code using Slim to TF 2.0 is more involved than converting repositories that use v1.layers. In fact, it may make sense to convert your Slim code to v1.layers first, then convert to Keras.

More information read the [TF migration guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate#a_note_on_slim_contriblayers)